# SMTP Mail Client Python

Tags: python, syntax, smtp

I have to write a SMTP mail client in Python for class and am stuck on the first part of the assignment.  After much hassle I've gotten this far (using Free Portable SMTP server currently but will later need to use SSL or TLS for gmail).  Below is my code.  I get a 500 Syntax error when it gets to the RCPT TO part of the code.  Can anyone help?

```
from socket import *
msg = "\r\n I love computer networks!"
endmsg = "\r\n.\r\n"

# Choose a mail server
mailServer = 'localhost'
mailPort = 25

# Create socket called clientSocket and establish a TCP connection with mailserver
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocket.connect((mailServer, mailPort))
recv = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print 'test'
print recv
if recv[:3] != '220':
    print '220 reply not received from server.'

# Send HELLO command and print server response.
helloCommand = 'HELO Alice\r\n';
clientSocket.send(helloCommand)
recv1 = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print recv1
if recv1[:3] != '250':
    print '250 reply not received from server.'

# Send MAIL FROM command and print server response.
#command = "STARTTLS\r\n"
#clientSocket.send(command)
#recva = clientSocket.recv(1024)
#print(recva)
mailfromCommand = 'MAIL FROM: <mail@mail.com>\r\n.'
clientSocket.send(mailfromCommand)
recv1 = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print(recv1)
if recv1[:3] != '250':
    print('mail from 250 reply not received from server.')

# Send RCPT TO command and print server response.
rcpttoCommand = 'RCPT TO: <myemail@gmail.com>\r\n'
clientSocket.send(rcpttoCommand)
recv1 = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print(recv1)
if recv1[:3] != '250':
    print('rcpt to 250 reply not received from server.')

# Send DATA command and print server response
dataCommand = 'Data'
print(dataCommand)
clientSocket.send(dataCommand)
recv1 = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print(recv1)
if recv1[:3] != '250':
    print('data 250 reply not received from server.')

# Send message data.
message = raw_input('Enter Message Here: ')

# Fill in end# Message ends with a single period.
mailMessageEnd = '\r\n.\r\n'
clientSocket.send(message + mailMessageEnd)
recv1 = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print(recv1)
if recv1[:3] != '250':
    print('end msg 250 reply not received from server.')

# Send QUIT command and get server response.
quitCommand = 'Quit\r\n'
print(quitCommand)
clientSocket.send(quitCommand)
recv1 = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print(recv1)
if recv1[:3] != '250':
    print('quit 250 reply not received from server.')

    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Results:

```
test
220 localhost


250 Hello localhost


250 mail@mail.com Address Okay


RCPT TO: <myemail@gmail.com>


500 Syntax Error


rcpt to 250 reply not received from server.
Data
```

Comment: Are you not allowed to use [`smtplib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html) from the standard library and/or third-party packages?

Comment: Meanwhile, [TCP sockets are byte streams, not message streams](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/sockets-are-byte-streams-not-message.html). Each `recv` could get half a line of data from the server, or seven and a half lines; you can't assume each one gets one line. You need to buffer and parse. Or just use `makefile` to let Python do that (which works for any line-by-line protocol like SMTP), and use `sendall` instead of `send`, and you're done.

Comment: We were given a base skeleton code that went all the way up until the MAIL FROM commands.  After that we had to fill out the rest.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely problem is this one:

```
mailfromCommand = 'MAIL FROM: <mail@mail.com>\r\n.'
```

Notice the extra `.` at the end? So, what you're sending the server ends up being:

```
MAIL FROM: <mail@mail.com>
.RCPT TO: <myemail@gmail.com>
```

And `.RCPT` is a syntax error.

---

However, there are two other very serious problems in the code.

The first is that there's no guarantee that [`send`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send) sends all the data you give it. That's why it returns the number of bytes actually sent. So, you could easily have ended up sending it part of a command.

This one is trivial to solve: just use `sendall` instead of `send`.

---

The second is that there's no guarantee that each `recv` will get exactly one line of data. It may get 6 characters in one `recv`, then 19 lines in the next. [TCP sockets are byte streams, not message streams](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/sockets-are-byte-streams-not-message.html), and it's up to you to build a message stream on top of it for your protocol.

Imagine what happens if you get `250 mail@mail.com Addr` in one `recv`, and then `ess OK\r\n250 myemail@gmail.com Address OK\r\n` in the next. You're going to check whether the second one starts with `250`, find that it doesn't, and fail.

This one is not quite as trivial to solve in general—normally you have to buffer and parse out messages, which means either writing a generator, or reorganizing your code completely.

But in the case of line-by-line protocols like SMTP, it's easy: just use [`makefile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.makefile), which gives you back a file object that you can iterate over or call `readline` on, and it will magically handle the buffering for you.

---

It looks like all three of these bugs are apparently in the code your teacher gave you. Not to mention things like the stray semicolon at the end of `helloCommand = 'HELO Alice\r\n'` (which is a red flag for code written by someone who doesn't actually know Python). You may want to read the [Socket Programming HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html), or, better, a more complete tutorial (that Google can hopefully find for you) so you learn how to actually write working programs instead of broken nonsense that works almost 99% of the time on localhost on your platform when the computer's not too busy.

Comment: Thank you for that catch. I do appreciate your help but it looks like this skeleton code was from our textbook as well. I have never programmed in Python before so I am just trying to get this to work. Ive gotten it past that error but now when I get down to the part of "Enter Message Here: ", I get the prompt in the shell and enter a message and hit enter, but then the program does nothing. I did some google searching and came across this guy's video and I can't see many if any differences between his and mine code.  http://strantalis.wordpress.com/2012/10/14/python-assignment-3-smtp-client/

Comment: @user2946832: Stack Overflow is not a good way to get someone to interactively debug your program, fixing each problem you run into one by one. You asked why you were getting that 500 error, I explained it, and now that part of your code works. If you have a new question, and you think it's worth asking on SO question, accept this answer then ask a new question (putting links from each one to the other).

Comment: @user2946832: Meanwhile, the extra "." was in the textbook? Then go to the textbook's website and see if they have an "Errata" section. If they do, it should tell you about all the bugs in the code they published, and how to fix them.

Comment: @user2946832: At any rate, the fact remains that you're trying to learn how to write sockets software in Python from someone who doesn't actually understand sockets or Python very well. If you're just looking to pass a class or something, maybe that's fine. If you want to actually learn, you will do better to find somewhere else to learn from.